# How do I exclude a namespace from dotcover using xml?

Tags: c#, teamcity, dotcover

I would like to exclude some namespaces from my test coverage statistics. We're using xml for our dotcover configuration.

For example, we exclude our test projects this way:

```
<Filters>
    <ExcludeFilters>
        <FilterEntry>
            <ModuleMask>*Tests</ModuleMask>
        </FilterEntry>
    </ExcludeFilters>
</Filters>
```

But I can't figure out how to do it for a C# namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use a `ClassMask`, if you don't mind "sub-namespaces" being excluded too. Suppose you want to expose `Foo.Bar`, you could have:

```
<FilterEntry>
    <ClassMask>Foo.Bar.*</ClassMask>
</FilterEntry>
```

If you *do* have "sub-namespaces" you could probably use `IncludeFilters` to explicitly include them again, although I haven't tried that.